# TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'float' object

Tags: python, list

I am trying to solve a problem and trying to get input from the user and append that in a list. But i am getting this error message.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list2 = []
    lsit = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        
        list.append(score)
        list.append(name)
        list2.append(list)  
    print(list2)
```

Comment: 1) you have a typo `lsit`. 2) dont use builtin `list` as variable name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have corrected it and posted the correct thing here for anyone else looking for the same thing,

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the name from **list** to something else. In my case I renamed it to '**list1**'.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list2 = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        list1 = []
        list1.append(score)
        list1.append(name)
        list2.append(list1)  
    print(list2)
```

Comment: You really should use maningful names for your variables.